# Is bad memory an issue for Windows Server Software Raid 5 resync?

Tags: windows, memory, raid, software-raid, windows-server

So, I have a setup at home where I run a Windows server 2019 running a Software Raid 5 setup running over 5 disks created through disk manager. Since this is a home system, I haven't really found going for a proper hardware raid worth it (and those cheaper "home-use" raid cards just offloads the calculations to the CPU anyway and aren't battery backed). Server has 8 sticks of memory, divided over 2 sets of four (Set1 and Set2)

Now, a couple of weeks ago, the server crashed, black screen, totally unresponsive. Which after rebooting caused the raid array to start re-syncing.
Then it crashed again 2 days later. Looking into it, I found that one of the memory modules had gone very bad, and failed almost every test I could throw at it. So, I removed the set of 4 modules (Set1) that included this one, and left the second set (Set2) with four modules in there.

Now, the resync completed just fine on the memory I left in there (Set2), but, as I got the bad memory replaced, I replaced all the memory in the server including those left in to make sure all memory modules where of the same type and specs.

After removing that working set(Set2) from the server I decided to test them, and it turned out that one of those sticks were bad too, one of the sticks consistently fails at a single memory address. Not the unending list of error that the stick from Set1 had, but still an error.

And here lies the question. Is it possible that my parity data on the disks are bad?
I don't know enough about how this data is calculated and handled during the resync, or, since it is a very small amount of data, if it actually leave the CPU cache at all and even hit the main memory.
I am worried that if my parity data is bad, that will lead to a disaster the next time I need to replace a bad disk in the raid array.

I'm already of the mindset that unless someone convinces me otherwise that it is bad, but I am hoping someone with some deeper technical knowledge about how the software raid resync process in Windows works could confirm or deny it. Maybe there are checks in place that would actually detect and prevent this from being an issue? And if it is a risk of it being bad, is there a way I can force Windows to do a resync of the array to replace the parity data without doing the brute force power disconnect? (And I'd rather not deliberately fault the array by removing a disk either, as this would cause just the issue I want to avoid if the parity data is bad.)

And yes, I have up to date backups of everything with history.

Comment: This seems to be a common problem with Windows' old Logical Disk Manager, so I'd actually guess the _software_ is bad... Do note that it's basically obsolete and even Microsoft will tell you to not use it anymore -- it hasn't been maintained much since Win2000/XP, the replacement is Storage Spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And yes, I have up to date backups of everything with history.

That's really amazing! I thought I'll have to give you the standard lecture about backups. You may need them.

> Maybe there are checks in place that would actually detect and prevent this from being an issue?

That's what ECC RAM does. ECC modules can correct one erroneous bit flip per byte and detect all 2 bit errors (and some 2+). It will crash the machine in the latter case because that's safer than progressing with known-bad data.

ECC is very important in servers because without it, the system must blindly trust that the data in memory is correct. DDR5 spec even requires ECC for all modules.

It sounds like you didn't have ECC memory though, so you can't be sure your data is fine. I would generally assume the RAID cannot be trusted, because RAID5 can only detect errors, but not correct them properly (unless the filesystem can do that, which NTFS can't AFAIK). Scrubbing the array will make it consistent, but it's not guaranteed that the adjustments made will be correct.

You can either:

- Destroy the array, create a new one and restore from backup, or
- Scrub the array and compare hashes with known-good copies.

That's assuming that you know your backups are fine. That may not be the case if the source system was silently corrupting data.

Consider switching to ECC memory to prevent this in the future.

Comment: gronostaj is correct.  Switching to ECC will help.  And yes, making backups is important.  However, an oft overlooked aspects of backups is rarely mentioned:  test restorations!  Making regular backups is great, but if the backups are bad, then they arent backups.  You need to test your backups regularly to make sure they are working as intended.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortuantely, switching to ECC isn't a possibility without switching out the entire system. This is just a simple home server, so it isn't running server grade hardware. CPU is an Intel I9-7940x which doesn't support ECC, and as I need high performance, switching to server grade gets expensive.
When I mentioned checks, I was wondering if the raid software itself had additional verification of the calculations before writing them independent of the memory.
If no one comes in with proof to to the contrary, I am going to assume the array is bad and dump and re-create it.

Comment: @Remy The problem is any checks rely on memory being good too. You could try to calculate everything a number of times in different memory areas and comparing results, but that would be quite slow and still not exactly reliable. ECC is 100% reliable though. You can get ECC hardware relatively cheap nowadays: either older v3 Xeons on Chinese "X99" motherboards (actually running server-grade C602 chipset), or AMD Ryzens which have unofficial ECC support as long as the motherboard provides it too.

Comment: While I won't go for the complete system replacement that ECC would entail, I decided that if I had to scrub the entire array anyway, it was a good time to replace my old drives as well, so I went the route of obtaining some larger disks and going with a mirror setup under Windows Storage Spaces.